# Disqus SSO + RAILS Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, single-sign-on, disqus

I'm trying to implement Disqus SSO with Rails.

I've built an app using Devise, but cannot figure out what to do with the sso code found on the Disqus API recipes. All of the documentation seems to be focussed on PHP, not Ruby.

Where is the correct place to use this function with Rails + Devise?

https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/sso/ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby, but cannot find other resources on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use devise_cas_authenticatable gem

https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable

hope top help you